# ? appended to filename while copying from a ssh

Tags: shell-script, filenames, cp, newlines

I am using the command `cp error.log error$HOSTNAME.log`

the command works properly while running it separately in a server, but if it is run as script which uses ssh I am getting a `?` appended to the filename. In the script I am copying an error log locally using `ssh` from other server and in the name of `arerro$HOSTNAME.log` but this copies as `arerror$HOSTNAME.log?`

Comment: Try `scp` instead of `ssh` and `cp`

Comment: Use `dos2unix` on your script. And is it really `error` one place, then `arerro`, then `arerror`?! Details like this *can matter a lot*.

Answer (score 1):

It's highly likely that the file name does not in fact contain a question mark. Rather, the `ls` command displays this instead of a non-printable character. Given that this character comes at the end of a file name which you specified in your script, it's probably a carriage return.

Why would you have a carriage return in your script? Because you edited it in a Windows editor. Windows represents newlines with the two-character sequence CR, LF (carriage return, line feed), whereas Unix uses just the LF character. So from Unix's perspective your script contains a line on which the last character is the ordinary character CR.

Either edit your script with a Unix editor, or use a Windows editor that allows you to save with Unix line endings.

To fix the files that you've already created, you can use the following command:

```
cr=$(printf '\r')
find . -name "*$cr" -exec sh -c 'for x do mv "$x" "${x%.}"; done' _ {} +
```

Comment: Thanks alot Gilles!! I will try to use a unix editor and will update the result.